Post doc position but requirement in notification states masters
I recently interviewed for a post-doc position from a European country. The interview was a result of a cold mail I sent many months back to a professor. They replied back stating that a position is available and would I like to interview. After the interview, I was told that I am the preferred candidate and I would have to apply on the official portal.
Once the official notification came I was intrigued by the title of the advertisement as "Post Master's degree to carry research activities". The annexure too mentioned that I need to supply my MTech (Masters) degree. However, the application asks to enclose my PhD degree too. On inquiring from the professor about this, the reply was that Masters is the minimum required for the application process, and I will be awarded extra points for the PhD.
My question is, is this practice normal? If I take up this position, will the certificate post completion of this term equivalent to a post-doctoral experience?

Two possibilities (of many): (1) the funding is not specific to a "post doctoral" applicant, but the professor wants someone with a PhD who will get more done. (2) the professor has found that their HR department throws out post-doctoral applicants who have not yet gotten their PhD awarded (but will before signing on) because the applicants "don't meet requirements" (that is, HR doesn't understand).

And, I've never heard of getting a "certificate" for completion of a postdoc, and have never given one to one of my postdocs. The "certificate" is they get a real job...

@JonCuster Another "certificate" is your letter of recommendation.

@AndreasBlass - perhaps a regional language variation, but I've never seen that equivalence in American English.

I never heard one getting post doc solely on the basis of masters. Can you share the link where you found such information?

What is an "annexure," and do you have a PhD?

This situation seems "normal" insofar as there is usually a gap between the actual academic hiring criteria and the official university hiring process.
For example, one of my former university employers couldn't legally hire anyone who didn't meet the minimum job requirements, so that section would often be very basic ("speaks a language, has a degree in a semi-related field") to avoid losing applicants on a technicality. The formal job adverts were based on a HR template for legal reasons, which is why there could be a pretty steep tonal dissonance between the scientific project sections and everything else. I wouldn't read too much into the formal job title, or the exact phrasing of specific document requests.
It is normal for them to ask for all of your relevant degrees and work experience. Those impact both your qualifications for the job, and later on your actual postdoc salary (assuming your new country has some collective bargaining/standardized salary scale for postdocs, which is common).
I have no idea what a "certificate" for a postdoc is- for legal/cultural/language reasons, your job title might be slightly different than just "postdoc" (e.g. "post-doctoral research assistant", "scientific project worker (with doctoral degree)"). This depends on the country, but should be considered equivalent in the proper context.
